# How can i handle a 500 internal server error ? I need an error/ exception handling option for this on runtime.?

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, internal-server-error

I have an ajax request While executing it gives an internal server error 500 in PHP. It is due to a DB error. How can I catch this error and instead of stopping the execution, I need to show an error message? 
I use Codeigniter framework.
Thank you

Comment: It is happening when I try to upload the wrong data type to a particular field. For example if I try to insert varchar to a date datatype field.

Answer (score 1):

You can add error callback in AJAX request like:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
```

More info: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for replying.I've tried that. It's not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to trap it in PHP ?

If so, you can add a try/catch block :

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (\Exception $e) { // you can trap a more specific exception related to your DB
  // process error and return a message
}
```